# ASP.NET MVC 5 Use Web SSO with external IDP - WS Fed metadata not parsed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, http-redirect, ws-federation

I try use Web SSO with WS-Federation for external IDP from ASP.NET MVC 5 app.

ASP.NET app is Service Provider in this scenario.

For login I would like use SAML HTTP Redirect binding.

**External IDP WS-FED metadata:**

```
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="id-58j8Ew5J8B7hOu51hu5qYyIGsXc-"
                     cacheDuration="P0Y0M30DT0H0M0.0S" entityID="idp:domain.com"
                     validUntil="2016-07-24T18:51:12Z">
  <md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
      <dsig:KeyInfo xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <dsig:X509Data>
          <dsig:X509Certificate>
            <!-- CERT -->
          </dsig:X509Certificate>
          <dsig:X509IssuerSerial>
            <dsig:X509IssuerName><!--ISSUER--></dsig:X509IssuerName>
            <dsig:X509SerialNumber><!--SN--></dsig:X509SerialNumber>
          </dsig:X509IssuerSerial>
          <dsig:X509SubjectName><!--CN--></dsig:X509SubjectName>
        </dsig:X509Data>
      </dsig:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
      <dsig:KeyInfo xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <dsig:X509Data>
          <dsig:X509Certificate>
            <!-- CERT -->
          </dsig:X509Certificate>
          <dsig:X509IssuerSerial>
            <dsig:X509IssuerName>
              <!--ISSUER-->
            </dsig:X509IssuerName>
            <dsig:X509SerialNumber>
              <!--SN-->
            </dsig:X509SerialNumber>
          </dsig:X509IssuerSerial>
          <dsig:X509SubjectName>
            <!--CN-->
          </dsig:X509SubjectName>
        </dsig:X509Data>
      </dsig:KeyInfo>
      <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
      <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
      <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes192-cbc" />
      <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
      <md:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
                                  Location="https://domain.com/fed/idp/soap" index="1"
                                  isDefault="true" />
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                            Location="https://domain.com/fed/idp/samlv20"
                            ResponseLocation="https://domain.com/fed/idp/samlv20" />
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                            Location="https://domain.com/fed/idp/samlv20"
                            ResponseLocation="https://domain.com/fed/idp/samlv20" />
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                            Location="https://domain.com/fed/idp/samlv20" />
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                            Location="https://domain.com/fed/idp/samlv20" />
  </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

**Auth settings in Start.up.cs:**

```
   public partial class Startup
    {

        private static readonly string realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
        private static readonly string adfsMetadata = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ADFSMetadata"];


        public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender,
                                                     X509Certificate certificate,
                                                     X509Chain chain,
                                                     SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //only for dev purpose
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            var wsFedOpt = new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,
                AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    SaveSigninToken = true, 
                },
            };

            app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(wsFedOpt);
        }
    }
```

When I run app I get error :

**Sequence contains no elements**

**Description:**

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

> [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source) +264
>      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.d__1.MoveNext() +576
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +11532712
>      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.d__3.MoveNext() +1236

Now I don’t know what is bad ? External IDP federation metadata, ASP.NET MVC configuration or something else.

When I tried external SP with external IDP during login it call HTTP GET, URI format is:

```
https://domain.com/fed/idp/samlv20?SAMLRequest=
```

A then I am redirect to external IDP login page.

I tried same configuration process with local IDP ([Identity Server v3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3)) it works.

When I use my local SP, auth  is also configured based on local IDP (Identity Server v3) metadata during login it call HTTP GET:

```
https://localhost:44333/core/wsfed?wtrealm=urn%3amvc5&wctx=WsFedOwinState%3dqNRmL2H9VZcEDKooeSF5nywV2vAHUDLXRSA77oe8jyVwZtGjpgRquhqYNUPbH28vrhm55zuEBYZnRw_k2nK-a97HHv9tiYLnwt4G19i1-q0&wa=wsignin1.0&wreply=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44392%2f
```

and then I am redirect to IDP Login page.

Maybe I need achieve ASP.NET use URI in format **https://domain.com/fed/idp/samlv20?SAMLRequest=** for SAML HTTP Redirect binding.

Thank you for any helpful feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are confusing protocols. The metadata is for the SAML2 Protocol (SAML2P for short) and not for the WS-Federation protocol.

You need a SAML2P owin middleware instead of the WS-Fed middleware. Unless you can get the Idp to use WS-Federation that is.